# ANOVA showing significance despite large variance within variables

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I am looking for an intuition on why ANOVA indicates that the difference between two variables is significant although I see that the variance within each variable is quite large.

This is how the mean and error bars showing the standard deviation look like for the two variables:

[image: mean and variance of two variables]

And the one-way ANOVA for the two samples (using this library https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html) indicates:

F-statistic: 9.584232820104393 p-value: 0.0020408541413054304

Do you think the result looks odd?

Comment: All statistical tests have sample size as a key input. This means that tests based on large samples will show significance even in the absence of *meaningful* differences.  ML algorithms are particularly vulnerable to this truism which is why ML enthusiasts obsession with accuracy and statistical significance is so misplaced. More recent heuristics suggest using effect sizes as the better measure of whether or not a significant result *matters*, the F-statistic for your data being a good proxy for same. That said, what are the sample sizes for the two buckets being compared?

Comment: Both variables have 351 samples. That's interesting, but how do I take the sample size into account?

Comment: If you examine the literature about ANOVA tests you'll see that the sample sizes are in the denominator.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what is your proposal for correctly measuring statistical significance in this case. You said that the F-statistic is a good proxy. So what does a value of 9.58 tell me?

Comment: You have already reported the statistical significance with the p-value.  It looks correct for these data.  The point is that you have large enough sample sizes to detect a difference that is relatively small.  You might want to study the distinction between *statistical significance* and *effect size.*